# strange issue with simple rabbitmq erlang message direct queue getter

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

A basic RabbitMQ install with user guest/guest.

Given the following simple erlang test code for RabbitMQ (erlang client), I am getting the error bellow.  The queue TEST_DIRECT_QUEUE exists and has 7 messages in it, and the RabbitMQ server is up and running.

If I try to create a new  with a declare API command, I **also** get a similar error. 
**Overall the error appears during any the << channel:call >> command**

Any thoughts ? Thanks.

=ERROR REPORT==== 16-Feb-2013::10:39:42 ===

Connection (<0.38.0>) closing: internal error in channel (<0.50.0>): shutdown

```
** exception exit: {shutdown,{gen_server,call,
                                     [<0.50.0>,
                                      {call,{'queue.declare',0,"TEST_DIRECT_QUEUE",false,false,
                                                             false,false,false,[]},
                                            none,<0.31.0>},
                                      infinity]}}
 in function  gen_server:call/3 (gen_server.erl, line 188)
 in call from test:test_message/0 (test.erl, line 12)
```

==============================================

```
-module(test).
-export([test_message/0]).
-include_lib("amqp_client/include/amqp_client.hrl").
-record(state, {channel}).

test_message() ->

    {ok, Connection} = amqp_connection:start(#amqp_params_network{}),
    {ok, Channel} = amqp_connection:open_channel(Connection),
    Get = #'basic.get'{queue = "TEST_DIRECT_QUEUE"},
    {#'basic.get_ok'{}, Content} = amqp_channel:call(Channel, Get),   <=== error here
    #'basic.get_empty'{} = amqp_channel:call(Channel, Get),
    amqp_channel:call(Channel, #'channel.close'{}).
```

Comment: to clarify, I tried this with code from RabbitMQ 3.0.1 and 3.0.2. The client erlang API was properly verified as corresponding to the server version. Also, the server and client are on the same host, without any firewall in-between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have identified the issue myself after some frustrating hours. Overall, let me confess to be upset with the vague tutorias and documentation about RabbitMQ.... Anyways, here is what the problem was:

1) Queue Names are supposed to be in binary form, therefore preceded by "<<" and superceded by ">>". For example : <<"my queue name">> ( quotes included as well )

2) In a different scenario where I was trying to create the queue with **queue.declare**, the fact that the queue already existed was not a problem, but the fact that the queue was durable and the **queue.declare** did not specify that set of parameters caused the program to throw an error and interrupt execution. This is an unfortunate behavior where normally, developers would expect the queue matching to be done simply by name and then proceed. So to fix that I had to specify the **durable** value.

Here is a simple working code:

```
-module(test).
-export([test/0]).
-include_lib("amqp_client/include/amqp_client.hrl").

test() ->
{ok, Connection} = amqp_connection:start(#amqp_params_network{}),
{ok, Channel} = amqp_connection:open_channel(Connection),
Declare = #'queue.declare'{queue = <<"TEST_DIRECT_QUEUE">>, durable = true},
#'queue.declare_ok'{} = amqp_channel:call(Channel, Declare),
Get = #'basic.get'{queue = <<"TEST_DIRECT_QUEUE">>, no_ack = true},
{#'basic.get_ok'{}, Content} = amqp_channel:call(Channel, Get),
#amqp_msg{payload = Payload} = Content.
```